# Magento doesn't show product in catalog

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 and newly added products doesn't show in catalog but in Admin Panel they are. Could anyone advise me?

Thanks

---

system.log

```
2014-06-04T10:49:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): requestShippingRates
2014-06-04T10:52:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): requestShippingRates
```

exception.log

```
#16 {main}
2014-06-04T10:29:09+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Neplatný typ bloku: Mage_Catalog_Block_Adbanner' in /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Neplatn?? typ b...')
#1 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/adbanne...', Array)
#2 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/adbanne...', 'catalog.banad')
#3 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/adbanne...', 'catalog.banad')
#4 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: have any  file  Mage>Catalog>Block>Adbanner????

Comment: in Mage>Catalog>Block isn't Adbanner folder

Answer (score 2):

Double check following

1. Is product active (Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > General > Status (should be enabled)
2. Does product have sufficient inventory (Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > Inventory. Qty must 1 or more, Stock Availability sud be In Stock*
3. Is product assigned to appropriate category (Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > Categories, see if it is assiged category you are looking
4. Is product assigned to right website (Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > Websites, see if product is assiged website you looking
5. Is product set visible (Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > General > Visibility, visibility catalog

*Subjected to Inventory Management option in setting

Comment: All is checked and is OK.

I added test product and save it to category, which was empty before. When I open product in Catalog > Manage Products > {Your Product} > Categories, I see that in category is one product (the test product), but the category is gray (http://i.stack.imgur.com/7U8WL.png) and the category isn't visible in e-shop.

Comment: Did you enabled that category as I said above?

Comment: Yes, I did. After I did open the enabled category, I see the error which I did post (http://i.gyazo.com/9202ac212188d74603e61151ca37140b.png). But count of products in database is the same as count of products in Admin Panel.